# Equivalent of -Xfrontend -debug-time-function-bodies for Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, clang

In Swift, you can use `-Xfrontend -debug-time-function-bodies` to see which of your functions are compiling slowly. Is there an equivalent for Objective-C?

Comment: No, because ObjC compiles fast enough that it doesn't matter. :p

Comment: We have some horrifying Obj-C++ ones that, well, ...